# Is there any pitfall of using ref as conditional statement?

Tags: reactjs

*Context: I am trying to scroll view to props.toBeExpandItem item which keeps changing depending on click event in parent component. Every time a user clicks on some button in parent component I want to show them this list and scroll in the clicked item to view port. Also I am trying to avoid adding ref to all the list items.*

I am using react ref and want to add it conditionally only once in my component. My code goes as below. In all cases the `option.id === props.toBeExpandItem` would be truthy only once in loop at any given point of time. I want to understand will it add any overhead if I am adding `ref=null` for rest of the loop elements?

```
export const MyComponent = (
  props,
) => {
  const rootRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.toBeExpandItem && rootRef.current) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        rootRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
      });
    }
  }, [props.toBeExpandItem]);

  return (
    <>
      {props.values.map((option) => (
        <div
          key={option.id}
          ref={option.id === props.toBeExpandItem ? rootRef : null}
        >
          {option.id}
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't actually understand what you are trying to achieve here. But from the looks of it something seems off. Like you are assigning new value to your ref on every loop. if your list item to scroll is in the middle of a list then the element on your ref will be replaced by another list item ref.

Comment: I am trying to scroll view to `props.toBeExpandItem` item which keeps changing depending on click event in parent component. Every time a user clicks on some button in parent component I want to show them this list and scroll in the clicked item to view port. Also I am trying to avoid adding ref to all the list items.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to avoid having refs on everything? If you have so many items that it is impacting virtualization, you probably need a different solution (such as a virtualized list). While what you have probably works, you may be better off passing in a property indicating what the "current" item's id, and scrolling to it if needed.

Comment: The only real downside I see to what you're doing is that, if your option entry was expensive to render, you may end up with unnecessary re-renders for both the previous and current value due to the `ref` property changing

Comment: I suspect you also have a strange usability issue...the scroll into view will happen when you make the change, but also anytime this component re-renders. So if the user scrolls away, they may be randomly yanked back. You may want to look for ways to avoid that.

Comment: Mostly I am avoiding refs to all elements as in that case I have to maintain copy of all refs in `const rootRef = useRef(null)`. Which I feel is unnecessary as at anytime only one item needs to be scrolled in. Also about usability issue I think scroll should not happen on each render as that is covered in useEffect(Unless props.toBeExpandItem changes)

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your recent comment, you can get the target from your click handler event. Will this work according to your ui?

```js
const handleClick = (e) => {
 e.target.scrollIntoView()
}

return (
  <ul>
   <li onClick={handleClick}>Milk</li>
   <li onclick={handleClick}>Cheese </li>
 </ul>
)
```